# Iterate variables over binary combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, boolean

Is there a simple way to loop variables through all possible combinations of true/false? For example, say we have a function:

```py
def f(a, b, c):
  return not (a and (b or c))
```

Is there a way to loop `a,b,c` through `000`, `001`, `010`, `011`, `100`, etc.?

My first thought was to loop through the integers and get the bit that corresponds to the variable position, like so:

```py
for i in range (8):
  a = i & 4
  b = i & 2
  c = i & 1
  print(f(a,b,c), " ", a,b,c)
```

It seems to work, but `a`, `b`, and `c` when printed out are all integers, and integers interact with logical operators differently than booleans. For example, `4 and 2` equals `2`, and `9 or 3` equals `9`. I don't mind it too much, it just took some thinking through to convince myself this doesn't matter.

But the question still stands, is there a still simpler way to loop through all possible true/false or 0/1 values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product


for a, b, c in product([True, False], repeat=3):
  print(f(a,b,c), " ", a,b,c)
```

If you really want integers 1 and 0, just replace `[True, False]` with `[1, 0]`. There's little reason to treat integers as bit arrays here.